# Evaluating limits of integration of double integral

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^2 \!\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}} \! \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

What confuses me is that $y$ goes from $0$ to $2$, but the region of integration on the plane $xy$ is a unit circumference centered at $(1,0)$. How can $y$ go from $0$ to $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What confuses me is that y goes from 0 to 2,

in your integral is $x$ that goes in $[0;2]$

$y$ goes in $[0;\sqrt{2x-x^2}]$

---

I understand that the text of your exercise can get you confused...this is the same integral as yours

$$\int_0^2\left[ \int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}f(x,y)dy  \right]dx$$

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but the exercise was given with that particular order of integration dxdy. Does not it mean that the outer limits of integration refer to y?

Comment: @Brasilian_student: the integration order $dxdy$ can get you confused, I understand, but it is evident that the integral with the bound expressed w.r.t. $x$ is in $dy$ thus the other one is in $dx$. I wrote you integral in a more readable form

Comment: @Brasilian_student, This answer is correct.

Comment: I understand that this is the right integral. Again, what confuses me is: should the exercise have been written in the first place with dydx? Writing it as dxdy does it make it wrong?

Comment: @Brasilian_student : formally $dx\cdot dy=dy\cdot dx$ thus there are no errors...of course the notation $dy\cdot dx$ would help you in understanding the integral...

Comment: Oh, I see. I really thought that the order we put dxdy or dydx was related to the order of the outer and inner integrals.